# How to delete a Relationship in Laravel that could be null?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

When the User decides to deactivate his account, I'm deleting every other table that belongs to the user as well.

In App\User:

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::deleting(function ($user) {
        $user->privacy->delete();
        $user->info->delete();

        $user->comments->each->delete();

        //If connected
        $user->instagram->delete(); //my Problem
    });
}

public function instagram(){
    return $this->hasOne(SocialInstagramAccount::class);
}
```

Is there a good way how to use the existing Relationship to delete the model if could be null?

With the code above I get: "Call to a member function delete() on null" when the User didn't login with Instagram. Clearly null->delete() does not work.

Comment: using soft deletes?

Comment: @MuhammadNauman no

Comment: Why are you not using foreign keys? So that database take care of it itself?

Comment: @MuhammadNauman Hmm... good point. I have a look if it works

Comment: Let me know if you need help there. Just use `CASCADE` on `onDelete`

Comment: @MuhammadNauman it worked! Now I'm curious if jonas answer works as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```php
$user->instagram()->delete();
$user->comments()->delete();
```